# How to use the interception mechanism in Entity Framework 6.3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

We need to add a new functionality in our app, such that for SELECT queries performed by our DbContext on its DbSets, for example when calling MyDbContext.Users, or MyDbContext.Students etc (User and Student inherit from a BaseEntity class, which includes a propery IsActive), we will be able to intercept them, check if the entity is of this base type BaseEntity, and modify the queries in some way, for example add a where clause to check if IsActive is true. I've tried to look into the **IDbCommandInterceptor** interface but its methods, including the one that is probably relevent to me, **ReaderExecuting**, intercept all kinds of SELECT statements performed on the database, not just the ones for the MyDbContext's dbsets.
How can I do this in the correct way?

Thanks, ashilon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interceptors, in this instance, are probably not what you want.  They intercept all queries for all DbContexts and you can only modify the SQL directly.  This is too dangerous when you want to add a where clause because joins could mess everything up.

If you have a repository or some base class all queries go through, do it there.  If you are always doing context.Students.Where(...) then there is a sneaky thing you can do, but not entirely sure if this'll work but I don't see why it wouldn't.

On your DbContext class, I would change all the DbSet property namesd, like Students, to StudentsDbSet.  I would then add this property to replace it:

```
public IQueryable<Student> Students 
{ 
    get { return StudentdsDbSet.Where(a => a.IsActive); }
}
```

All old code would now refer to this property that forces IsActive only records.  Then if you needed non-active students, you could do StudentsDbSet.Where(...) and you'd be good to go.

Comment: Excellent answer Daniel! Great explanation and great workaround. Just a small question: Is there a reason why you're returning IQueryable instead of DbSet? Does StudentsDbSet also need to be IQueryable? Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you do Where clause, this will now be IQueryable.  It won't return a DbSet anymore.  You need a DbSet property on Context because that is how Entity Framework knows how to hook up the mappings, I believe.